# Way of the bicycle

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm a karate-do practitioner. And I love the meaning of DO (way). I'm building a cyclist group. And I want to call it "The way of two wheels". Does it make sense to call it Niwa-Do?

Answer (score 7):

二輪 (in the sense of "two wheels / bicycle") is read にりん, so "The way of two wheels" could be...

> [二輪道]{にりんどう}

It looks like some people are already using it, eg [「大日本二輪道連合会」](http://gmcu.fc2web.com/), [「二輪道カップ」](https://www.google.co.uk/search?biw=1093&bih=500&sxsrf=ACYBGNQ8vDcE3qf_AgDHB5EpYLR1UUKSug%3A1568907447614&ei=t6CDXfuVJcOchwPgyKLICQ&q=%22%E4%BA%8C%E8%BC%AA%E9%81%93%E3%82%AB%E3%83%83%E3%83%97%22&oq=%22%E4%BA%8C%E8%BC%AA%E9%81%93%E3%82%AB%E3%83%83%E3%83%97%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i4i37j0j0i30l3.12140.14473..14955...0.0..0.220.1476.0j8j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i7i30j0i7i5i30j0i7i4i30j0i4i37i32j0i4i30.O_gxDE6xMoE&ved=0ahUKEwi7zebYm93kAhVDzmEKHWCkCJk4ChDh1QMICw&uact=5)
(It seems they're using 二輪 in the sense of "motorcycle / 自動二輪", though...)

Comment: 二輪と言えば[オートバイ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%83%90%E3%82%A4)をイメージしてしまうのです。ぱっと思いつかないのですが自転車のグループには何がいいんでしょうね .[二輪通行禁止の標識は自転車はダメ?](https://soudan1.biglobe.ne.jp/qa4593335.html)、二輪通行禁止でも、自転車は大丈夫らしいです。

Comment: @kimitanaka 法的には[オートバイは自動車](https://ja.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E3%81%AB%E3%81%8A%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B%E8%87%AA%E5%8B%95%E8%BB%8A)なので法律は一旦忘れた方が。いわゆる自転車も普通に二輪だと思いますが、まあ区別が大事なら"自転車道"とか"チャリ道"でも良いとは思います。

Comment: @naruto さん、"チャリ道"はいいかと思いましたけどね笑 自分にはぎごちなくても、"二輪道"でも意外と馴染むかもしれないですね。ご指摘ありがとうございます。